# Rails - Problems Passing Params Through link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

I'm trying to update the game_started attribute through a link_to. I've also tried using a form_for via hidden_field with no luck.

I also keep getting the below errors

> ArgumentError in GamesController#update
>
> When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

**show.html.erb**

```
<% if @game.game_started %>
  # some code
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Start The Game", game_path(@game, :game_started => true), :method => :put %>
<% end %>
```

**GamesController**

```
def edit
end

def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])

  if @game.update_attributes (params[:game_started])
    redirect_to @game
  end
end

def game_params
  params.require(:game).permit(:game_type, :deck_1, :deck_2, :user_1, :user_2, :game_started)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
if @game.update_attributes (game_started: params[:game_started])
  redirect_to @game
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In **show.html.erb** should change to

```
<%= link_to "Start The Game", game_path(@game, :game => {:game_started => true}), :method => :put %>
```

In **Controller** should be

```
if @game.update_attributes (game_started: params['game']['game_started'])
  redirect_to @game
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're passing the wrong arguments into the `update_attributes` method call. It's expecting a hash like `{game_started: params['game_started']}`, while you're just giving it the value of `params['game_started']`. When you just give it a value, it won't know which field in the model to update. So change your code to:

```

```
if @game.update_attributes(game_started: params[:game_started])
   redirect_to @game
end
```

```